# Change the image on my website Like Button

Tags: image, facebook-like

It is possible to change the thumbnail image that users see after hitting a "Like" button on my website without using the Javascript SDK?

I'm currently using this iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.itsmorethanatextbook.com?show_faces=false" 
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

Hopefully this is a simple question.  :)

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

Try to set

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YOURWESITE.COM/IMAGE.JPG"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR WEBSITE TITLE"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://YOURWESITE.COM/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

in your HEADER, after test your web site with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug the url linter :)